# Layer popups prevented by additional code in onEachFeature

Tags: leaflet

Working in leaflet-0.7.3, I have built custom popups using properties of geoJson data using `layer.bindPopup` in `onEachFeature`. However I am also attempting to use `layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.fid` in `onEachFeature` in order to make use of a function to move between features with an external control.

This function (`clickOnMapItem` in the below code extract) works, and I'm intending to make use of it with NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons outside of the map.

However after the inclusion of `layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.fid` in `onEachFeature` the pop ups no longer appear. How can I perform both tasks successfully inside `onEachFeature`?

I've included a code extract below.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
layer.bindPopup('<b>Location: </b>' + feature.properties.name);
layer.on({
click: getName
});
//including this next line seems to prevent the popups
layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.fid;
}

function clickOnMapItem(itemId) {
var id = parseInt(itemId);
//get target layer by it's id
var layer = geojson.getLayer(id);
//fire event 'click' on target layer 
layer.fireEvent('click');
}

function getName(e) {
//info.update is a function used to populate an external div
info.update(e.target.feature.properties);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact cause of the issue with `layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.fid;` remains unknown (as YaFred points out, it's internal to Leaflet and therefore has no supporting documentation), but I did discover an alternative solution that I hope will help others.

Instead of `layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.fid;`, I used `layers[feature.properties.fid] = layer;`, having previously called `var layers = {};`, based on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255260/93292) answer. I've included the updated code extract, which builds Next and Previous functionality that can be used to scroll through the layer.

```
var currentPhoto;
var layers = {};


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<b>Location: </b>' + feature.properties.name);
    layer.on(
        "click",function(e){getName(e);
        currentPhoto = parseInt(layer.feature.properties.fid);
    });
    layers[feature.properties.fid] = layer;
}

// call from outside map
function highlightFeature(fid){
    layers[fid].fireEvent('click');
}

$('#prev').click(function() {
    highlightFeature(currentPhoto-1);
});

$('#next').click(function() {
    highlightFeature(currentPhoto+1);
});

function getName(e) {
    //info.update is a function used to populate an external div
    info.update(e.target.feature.properties);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT use `_leaflet_id`

It's internal to leaflet and you won't find any documentation about it.

For what you want to achieve, I would not use `fireEvent('click')` to open a popup. There is a method `openpopup` for that.

Comment: `fireEvent('click')` is used to run the `getName` function, which passes the properties of the feature for use in an external div. It isn't used to open a popup.

I could potentially remove `layer.fireEvent('click')` and directly run `getName` and try to force the popp with `openpopup`, but I would still need the `layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.fid` part to be able to navigate through features with an outside control. I haven't been able to find an alternative to this.