# Bind layer to onEachFeature in functional component with react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

In rendering a `react-leaflet` map, I am having a bit of trouble binding the context of `onEachFeature` to the handler.

Here's the relevant handler

```
function handleInteractive(
  feature: any,
  layer: L.Layer,
  params: AdditionalBindingParams,
) {
  const { space, store } = params;
  layer.bindTooltip(space.name, {
    permanent: true,
    direction: 'center',
  });

  const onClick = () => {
    const activeSpaceId = getSpaceLayerId(feature);
    const centerFn = this.getBounds; //also tried layer.getBounds
    const coordinates = centerFn ? centerFn().getCenter() : undefined;
    if (store) {
      store.dispatch(setActiveMapLocation({ activeSpaceId, coordinates }));
    }
  };
  layer.on('click', onClick, layer);
}
```

The last line `layer.on('click', onClick, layer);` is binding `this` correctly when I use a breakpoint, but it still fails when invoked in code.

[image: layer-context]

As you can see, `this` in the local scope is bound to `NewClass` which is the target layer. It should also be noted that the other layer handlers are bound correctly (e.g. `bindTooltip`).

That said, the incoming argument `layer` in the function, is undefined. Further, when invoked inside of `leaflet`, getBounds is defined, but `this` is `undefined`

[image]

Here's how the component is rendered (functional component, not a class component)

```
 <GeoJSON
    key={document_id}
    onEachFeature={onEachFeature} /// also tried with `.bind(this)`
    data={...props} />
```

There are similar SO issues out there, (e.g. [another binding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504884/layer-popups-prevented-by-additional-code-in-oneachfeature)), but I have not found a solution.

My hunch is that there is an arrow function somewhere in the underlying lib that is eating the context, but thought I would see if there was someone who could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a bit different route and avoid `this`, it might also be beneficial if you are moving towards React Hooks.

**Option 1**

Pass extra parameters via leaflet via [`.on` event](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#evented-on):

```
function handleEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on("click", (e) => {
      handleClick(e, layer);
    });
}

function handleClick(event, layer) {
  const bounds = layer.getBounds();
  console.log(bounds);
}
```

**Option 2**

Pass extra parameters via leaflet `L.bind` function:

```
function handleEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on("click", L.bind(handleClick, null, layer));
}

function handleClick(layer) {
  const bounds = layer.getBounds();
  console.log(bounds);
}
```

**Option 3**

Get `layer` via [`Event.target` property](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#event-target):

```
function handleEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on("click", handleClick);
}

function handleClick(event) {
    const bounds = event.target.getBounds();
    console.log(bounds);
}
```

> Note: leaflet package needs to be imported: `import * as L from "leaflet";`

Comment: A recap - 
`Option #1` ---> this is what I tried initially and does not bind. Layer is undefined.
`Option #2` ---> We have a winner!
`Option #3` ---> getBounds is undefined.

Option #1 seems most straightforward, and I don't understand why the layer is undefined, but #2 works.

Thanks for your help!